# Can't set the correct value in this while loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, colors, while-loop

I have translated this code to VB.NET which is a function to check if a image is grayscale.

```
private static unsafe bool IsGrayScale(Image image)
{
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
        }

        var data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

        var pt = (int*)data.Scan0;
        var res = true;

        for (var i = 0; i < data.Height * data.Width; i++)
        {
            var color = Color.FromArgb(pt[i]);

            if (color.A != 0 && (color.R != color.G || color.G != color.B))
            {
                res = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        bmp.UnlockBits(data);

        return res;
    }
}
```

The C# code is working but is not doing what I need so I did a little modifications trying to make a function which checks if a image has certain RGB color but the most important part is not working:

```
Dim color__1 = Color.FromArgb(pt(i))
```

Exception:

```
Error   1   Expression is not an array or a method, and cannot have an argument list.   C:\Visual Studio Projects\WindowsApplication9\WindowsApplication9\Form1.vb  21  47  WindowsApplication9
```

Here is the translated code:

```
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Public Class Form1

    Private Shared Function ImageHasColor(ByVal image As Image, ByVal R As Int32, ByVal G As Int32, ByVal B As Int32) As Boolean

        Using bmp = New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

            Using graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
                graph.DrawImage(image, 0, 0)
            End Using

            Dim data = bmp.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.[ReadOnly], bmp.PixelFormat)

            Dim pt = CType(data.Scan0, Integer)
            MsgBox(pt)
            Dim res As Boolean

            Dim i = 0
            While i < data.Height * data.Width
                Dim color__1 = Color.FromArgb(pt(i))

                If color__1.A <> 0 AndAlso color__1.R = R AndAlso color__1.G = G AndAlso color__1.B = B Then
                    res = True
                    Exit While
                End If

                System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)
            End While

            bmp.UnlockBits(data)

            Return res
        End Using
    End Function


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim bmp = New Bitmap("C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\PrtScr capture_3.jpg")
        MsgBox(ImageHasColor(bmp, 240, 240, 240))
    End Sub

End Class
```

> UPDATE:

Those codes works only for the first time, if I use it more than one time I get this error:

**Attempted to read or write protected memory**

1.

```
Private Shared Function ImageHasColor(ByVal image As Image, ByVal R As Int32, ByVal G As Int32, ByVal B As Int32) As Boolean

    Using bmp = New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

        Using graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            graph.DrawImage(image, 0, 0)
        End Using
        Dim color__1 As Color
        Dim byt
        Dim data = bmp.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.[ReadOnly], bmp.PixelFormat)

        Dim pt = CType(data.Scan0, Integer)

        Dim res As Boolean

        For i = 0 To data.Height * data.Width - 1

            color__1 = Color.FromArgb(Marshal.ReadInt32(pt, i * 4))

            If color__1.A <> 0 AndAlso color__1.R = R AndAlso color__1.G = G AndAlso color__1.B = B Then
                res = True
                Exit For
            End If

            'System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)
        Next

        bmp.UnlockBits(data)

        Return res
    End Using
End Function
```

2.

```
Private Shared Function ImageHasColor(ByVal image As Image, ByVal R As Int32, ByVal G As Int32, ByVal B As Int32) As Boolean

    Using bmp = New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

        Using graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            graph.DrawImage(image, 0, 0)
        End Using
        Dim color__1 As Color
        Dim byt
        Dim data = bmp.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.[ReadOnly], bmp.PixelFormat)

        Dim pt = CType(data.Scan0, Integer)

        Dim res As Boolean

        Dim i = 0
        While i < data.Height * data.Width


            color__1 = Color.FromArgb(Marshal.ReadInt32(pt, i * 4))

            If color__1.A <> 0 AndAlso color__1.R = R AndAlso color__1.G = G AndAlso color__1.B = B Then
                res = True
                Exit While
            End If

            System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)
        End While

        bmp.UnlockBits(data)

        Return res
    End Using
End Function
```

> UPDATE:

This code seems to be working

```
Private Shared Function ImageHasColor(ByVal image As Image, ByVal R As Int32, ByVal G As Int32, ByVal B As Int32) As Boolean

    Try
        Using bmp = New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

            Using graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp) : graph.DrawImage(image, 0, 0) : End Using

            Dim Pixel_Color As Color

            Dim Ditmap_Data = bmp.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.[ReadOnly], bmp.PixelFormat)

            Dim pt As IntPtr = CType(Ditmap_Data.Scan0, IntPtr)

            For i = 0 To Ditmap_Data.Height * Ditmap_Data.Width - 1

                Pixel_Color = Color.FromArgb(Marshal.ReadInt32(pt, i * 4))

                If Pixel_Color.A <> 0 AndAlso Pixel_Color.R = R AndAlso Pixel_Color.G = G AndAlso Pixel_Color.B = B Then
                    bmp.UnlockBits(Ditmap_Data)
                    Return True
                End If

            Next

            bmp.UnlockBits(Ditmap_Data)
            Return False

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: I never understood why people felt the need to translate between .NET languages. Just add a C# project with the class, and reference the project - you can then use it in any .NET language.

Comment: The original C# code is not doing what I need, do you readed my question?, also my full project is written in VB and also I want to learn the way to do things in VB not in C#, if I only copy/paste the C# code don't learn nothing and still having the problem, but thanks for your comment.

Comment: `The original C# code is not doing what I need, do you readed my question?` I did, but there's no mention about the C# code not working, only about the VB modification.

Comment: @Nolonar the C# code is working but don't have my requisites, I take the C# code example to make a few modifications to have my requisites, but I imagine the C# code use pointers and that's the problem. PS: sorry about my english

Comment: Why are you using a While instead of a For, by the way? It seems pretty straightforward...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you're just being contrarian. Why these UnlockBits in the loop? Do you see them in the original code? Remove them at once.

```
Private Shared Function HasColor(ByVal image As Image, ByVal toFind As Color) As Boolean

    Using bmp = New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

        Using graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            graph.DrawImage(image, 0, 0)
        End Using

        Dim data = bmp.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.[ReadOnly], bmp.PixelFormat)

        Dim pt = data.Scan0 'Since we can't use a pointer in VB.Net, we'll stick to IntPtr for now
        Dim res As Boolean = False

        For i=0 To data.Height * data.Width - 1
            Dim foundColor as Int32 = Marshal.ReadInt32(pt, i*4)

            If (foundColor and &HFF000000) <> 0 AndAlso ( (foundColor and &H00FFFFFF) = (toFind.ToArgb() and &H00FFFFFF) ) Then
                res = True
                Exit For
            End If

        Next

        bmp.UnlockBits(data)

        Return res
    End Using
End Function


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim bmp = New Bitmap("C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\PrtScr capture_3.jpg")
    MsgBox(ImageHasColor(bmp, Color.FromArgb(240, 240, 240)))
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: sorry that was a mistyp when copying 'cause I'm testing things, the code still hangs even with the try:UnlockBits inside the loop.

Comment: No now it don't hangs, but is throwing the memory access exception, can you test the For loop code which I've posted please?

Comment: I edited, this should be an accurate translation, tweaked to your ends.

Comment: can you correct this line please? **If (foundColor and &HFF000000) <> 0 AndAlso (foundColor and &H00FFFFFF) = (toFind.ToArgb() and &H00FFFFFF) ) Then**  when I delete the ")" char seems that I loose hex data of the hex values

Comment: I added a missing parenthesis. I hope this is enough, I'm not used to VB and its bad habit of using the same operator (`=`) for assignment and equality... If that still fails, use `.Equals()`

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring `pt` as an `IntPtr` and using the `Marshal` and `BitConverter` classes to read the integer there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tried declaring the pt as intptr but then it says: **"structure system.intpr cannot be indexed because it has no default property"**, Tried a example with marshal.copy but I don't know how to use marshal.copy or marshal.bitconverter for this even saw few examples, maybe a solution can be converting the image to a integer array www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=321048 but really it's so hard for me.

Comment: Which version of the .Net Framework are you using? The "easy" way requires .Net 4.0, I'll post the more complicated way if you're dependent on an earlier version.

Comment: not a problem for me to use FW4.0, the only thing that I would you to have in mind is I'm looking for ways to do it lightly (Marshal.Copy for example) and not with the slow "getpixel" method, thankyou for your time. here are a lot of examples that I've tested without success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598400/if-image-contains-specific-color-then

Comment: In fact, the `Marshal` class makes it even easier than I thought, and without the need for 4.0: Just using `Dim color__1 As Color = Color.FromARGB(Marshal.ReadInt32(pt, i*4))` should work.

Comment: the modification worked the first time, the second time it says "Attempted to read or write protected memory"

Comment: What's `System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(i), i - 1)` supposed to do? And why are you using InterLocked on a local variable is not exposed to other threads, ever?

Comment: sorry but I don't know, that's what I get when doing the online translation with a few c# to VB converters

Comment: Then you should replace loop and increment with a simple `For i=0 To data.Height * data.Width - 1`

Comment: Instead of a While I've tried using a simple For, I get the same result, the code worked for the first time but the next times I get that error about memory access, I think the marshal operation need to be "unloaded" or something else.

Comment: Please Update your question and show me your latest code, with `Marshal.ReadInt32` and `For`.

Comment: Oh now I remember your first recommendation, I've changed the pt declaration to intptr and now all is working good, thankyou for all

Comment: I have only one question before accepting your answer, maybe is a stupid question but... you are sure this is working as expected?: color__1 = Color.FromArgb(Marshal.ReadInt32(pt, i * 4))  I ask because I read about the need to get 3 bytes from nowhere and other 3 bytes and other 2 to convert that data to the real rgb, but I don't know anything about this. really what I want to ask is if all the things of the For loop code from my last updated code is correct